# Need to get creative writing a JavaScript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Need a little help with writing a regular expression that would match any of the following (without the quotes).

- "items="
- "items[]="
- "items[0]="

This is a little more complex than my regular expression knowledge goes.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make the bracket expression optional and the index expression optional as well.

```
/items(?:\[\d*\])?=/
```

- `items` matches the literal string `items`, as you know
- `(?: some stuff )?` makes the ' some stuff ' optional, and doesn't make a group.
- `\[` matches a literal `[`
- `\d*` matches zero or more digit characters
- `\]` matches a literal `]`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
/\bitems(\[\d*\])?=/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/it3JGXwY-FWX3RPx)

Answer (score 1):

```
/\bitems(\[\d*\])?=/
```

This will match any string of digits, not just 0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]]+/
```

...?
Or, according to your comment:

```
/items\[[0-9]*\]/  // this will match any numbers inside
/items\[[0-9]?\]/  // this will match nothing or one digit
/items\[0?\]/  // this will match only the digit zero or nothing
```

Which one is your aim?

Comment: that seems like it will match way more than you want...

Comment: What exactly is it you want to match - and what not? ... Is it just "items\[[0-9]?\]" ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
/\bitems(\[\d*\])?=/
```

- `\b` matches a word boundary (delete this if you want to match `items` as part of a larger string;
- `items` matches the string (fairly self explanatory)
- `\[\d*\]` matches a pair of square brackets containing zero or more digits;
- wrapping this in `()?` makes the contained match optional; then
- `=` the trailing equals is matched.